# Get l3build to install documentation?

Tags: l3build

Is it possible to get `l3build` to install documentation in the local texmf tree?

Running `l3build install` installs style files in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/<module>/` just fine, but it neither builds nor installs documentation to `$TEXMFHOME/doc/<module>/`.

Am I missing something? Or is this not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything: the `install` target alone doesn't build documentation. The logic here is that `install` is essentially for developers to do testing: once you want to release, a `ctan` build will be required and can be used to construct a TDS-style Zip file, which can then be copied into your local tree if required. However, most of the time you won't want to do that ...

One can request a complete installation by passing the `--full` flag to the `install` target.

Comment: Yeah, I realise it wouldn't get used often. I was mainly thinking of cases where someone wants to easily build and install from Git instead of CTAN.

Comment: @DavidPurton I can see that, but I'd hope this is only the case where there is a 'temporary' issue with a package. Even there, I'd normally expect to be sending a user a TDS-style zip file, rather than asking them to use a Git checkout ...

Comment: @DavidPurton Once I get round to revising how top-level targets are set up, it should be easy to add a switch for this. Perhaps next week ...

Comment: @JosephWright: I notice now that `l3build install --full` installs documentation.  Thank you!